# How to convert Excel Sumproduct formula into DAX

Tags: excel, dax

I have the following formula in excel which I need to convert into DAX.

Where '*volume*','_SalesTarget','_Sales' columns have decimal numbers and '*Category*' and '*Switch*' has text values

`SUMPRODUCT(--(_Category_='Sheeted'),--(_Switch_="Yes"),--(_SalesTarget<=_Sales),_Volume_)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
SUMX(
    'Table',
    IF(
        'Table'[_Category_] = "Sheeted",
        IF(
            'Table'[_Switch_] = "Yes",
            IF( 'Table'[_SalesTarget] <= 'Table'[_Sales], 'Table'[_Volume_] )
        )
    )
)
```

or:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM( 'Table'[_Volume_] ),
    FILTER(
        'Table',
        'Table'[_Category_] = "Sheeted"
            && 'Table'[_Switch_] = "Yes"
            && 'Table'[_SalesTarget] <= 'Table'[_Sales]
    )
)
```